# Difference in rolling back a statement and a transaction in JPA

Tags: java, jpa, rollback

JPA Query javadoc (see http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#executeUpdate()) says

```
int executeUpdate() Execute an update or delete statement. 
Returns: the number of entities updated or deleted 
Throws: 
IllegalStateException - if called for a Java Persistence query language SELECT statement or for a criteria query 
TransactionRequiredException - if there is no transaction 
QueryTimeoutException - if the statement execution exceeds 
  the query timeout value set and only the statement is rolled back 
PersistenceException - if the query execution exceeds 
  the query timeout value set and the transaction is rolled back
```

What's the difference between rolling back a statemente and a transaction? I mean, rolling back a transaction is pretty obvious, it will set the transaction to rollback and all the operations will be undone. But if the statement is rolled back (since it's an update/delete/insert operation), won't the whole transaction be also rolled back in this situation?

Was this QueryTimeoutException designed to be caught and allow the user to retry on timeout without affecting the transaction?

Comment: do yout still looking for an answer?

Answer (score 4):

> [A QueryTimeoutException is] thrown by the persistence provider when a query times out and only the statement is rolled back. The current transaction, if one is active, will be not be marked for rollback. [[QueryTimeoutException](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/QueryTimeoutException.html)]

The [QueryTimeoutException](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/QueryTimeoutException.html) is a specialization of the [PersistenceException](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/PersistenceException.html).

> [A PersistenceException is] thrown by the persistence provider when a problem occurs. All instances of PersistenceException **except for instances of NoResultException, NonUniqueResultException, LockTimeoutException, and QueryTimeoutException** will cause the current transaction, if one is active and the persistence context has been joined to it, to be marked for rollback. [[PersistenceException](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/PersistenceException.html)]

Therefore if a query times out don't matter which it will not cause a rollback of the transaction by default. That's why you have to do it always explicitly. For example if you want to rollback the transaction regardless which `PersistenceException` occurs.

```
catch(PersistenceException e) { ... tx.rollback(); ... }
```

But sometimes it makes sense to continue a transaction even a statement was not successful and a `QueryTimeoutException` occurs.

An example scenario is the time out during the execution of a statement which only persist an additional log record. Depending on your use case the time out of executing the log statement could not be critical otherwise it's critical if the core business process for example persisting the order times out. Therefore you don't want that the failed log statement will affect the persisting of the order. On the other hand if the persisting of the order fails the persisting of the log record should be roll backed. So you can always decide which query time out should cause a rollback.

A schematically example would be

```
...
try {
    ...
    queryNonCritical.execute(...);
}
catch(QueryTimeoutException e) {
    // not critical move on
    ...
}
...
try {
    ...
    queryCritical.execute(...);
}
catch(QueryTimeoutException e) {
    ...
    tx.rollback();
    ...
}
...
```